# Google Play services with API 7

Tags: android

I am using gradle to build my android app and have google play services defined as:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
```

The build works fine when I have minSdkVersion 8, but if I set it to 7 I get:

```
Error:
uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 7 cannot be smaller than version 8 declared in library com.google.android.gms:m:4.0.30
```

Is there a version of google play services that is compatible with API 7?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is not a version that is compatible with API less than 8.
http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/index.html